# Vba: display decimals with point and not coma

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have all numbers in a macro displayed with point and not coma

For Instance This display "0,03" but I would like "0.03":

```
Dim MyNumber As Single
MyNumber = 0.03
MsgBox (MyNumber)
```

I have tried a set of codes that does ***not*** work:

- this still displays the Coma:

  ```
  Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
  ```
- this still displays the Coma and does not apply to the whole macro

  ```
  MyNumber = Format(MyNumber, "##0.00")
  ```
- this displays dot instead of coma but does not apply to the whole macro

  ```
  MsgBox (Replace(MyNumber, ",", "."))
  ```

Thank you!

Comment: I believe this will be set in your Region and Language Control panel (in Win7 its Control Panels => Region and Language => Decimal symbol) Changing that should solve your problem.

Comment: @bamie9l : Thank you for the answer but I would like to do this only for the Macro, also if somebody use the macro from a different region set-up I would like that still the point is displayed.

Comment: If you want actions such as `MsgBox`, or `Debug.print` to display in a format different from your windows regional settings, you will need to format those values explicitly.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you for the answer, could you also tell me about the function `.WriteLine` to print text to a file? Otherwise If you are sure about it and write it bellow I can validate it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, the three functions bellows from Kernel32 Dynamic-link library have to be declared:

```
Private Declare Function GetUserDefaultLCID% Lib "kernel32" ()
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfoA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetLocaleInfoA Lib "kernel32" ( ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String) As Boolean
```

- The first will get the user default id
- The second will help to get the value of the locals (and therefore restore)
- The third will help to set the value of the locals

The local type value for the decimals is 14 (some likes to write &HE - hexadecimal E -)

Then the program has to look like this:

```
' record the settings in the variable LocalSettingsDecimal
Dim LocalSettingsDecimal As String
Dim Buffer As String
Buffer = String(256, 0)
Dim le As Integer
le = GetLocaleInfoA(GetUserDefaultLCID(), 14, Buffer, Len(Buffer))
LocalSettingsDecimal = Left(Buffer, le - 1)

' force decimal settings to '.'
Call SetLocaleInfoA(GetUserDefaultLCID(), 14, ".")

' body
Dim MyNumber As Single
MyNumber = 0.03
MsgBox (MyNumber)

' set back the decimal settings
Call SetLocaleInfoA(GetUserDefaultLCID(), 14, LocalSettingsDecimal)
```

Let's note that, unfortunately, In case the program body fail, the settings are not restored... but this still answer the issue

Answer (score 5):

This is easier said than done. In the VBA editor, the decimal separator is the dot.  However, the MsgBox function (and the Format function) will use the windows regional settings, and not the Excel settings, to format its results.

In order to have the MsgBox display a number using format settings of your choice, you need to create a string that has the value formatted as you want.

Here is one way of doing that:

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub dural()
 Dim S As String
 Dim D As Double
 Const myDecSep As String = "."

D = 1234.56

S = Format(D, "0.00") 'will format using the system separator

S = Replace(S, Application.DecimalSeparator, myDecSep)

MsgBox S

End Sub
```

---

Note that if you want to use both decimal and thousands separators, and if you are interchanging, for example, the comma and the dot, you need to do this twice so as not to replace all your commas with dots, or vice-versa

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub dural()
 Dim S As String
 Dim D As Double
 Const myDecSep As String = "."
 Const myThousSep As String = ","

D = 1234.56

S = Format(D, "#,##0.00")

S = Replace(S, Application.DecimalSeparator, Chr(1))
S = Replace(S, Application.ThousandsSeparator, Chr(2))
S = Replace(S, Chr(1), myDecSep)
S = Replace(S, Chr(2), myThousSep)

MsgBox S

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Thank you @RonRosenfeld! It is a very good answer and I will definitely come back to give a up-vote as soon as I get enough reputation. 
However After a lot of research, I could come up with a solution, still not beautiful, but that actually answer my question, I will validate this one as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this today, too.
Specifically, with the `FormatNumber` function.
Because I don't want to take @Jonathan's (very interesting) approach and change my f[lipp]ing system settings just to have power over how numbers are displayed (Seriously, Office, what is wrong with you??), I wrote a wrapper function to make `FormatNumber` use the **app settings**, instead of the *system settings*, after detecting whether it's necessary:

```
Public Function FormatNumberFixed(Expression As Variant, Optional NumDigitsAfterDecimal As Integer = -1, _
Optional IncludeLeadingDigit As Integer = -2, Optional UseParensForNegativeNumbers As Integer = -2, _
Optional GroupDigits As Integer = -2)
    FormatNumberFixed = FormatNumber(Expression, NumDigitsAfterDecimal, IncludeLeadingDigit, UseParensForNegativeNumbers, GroupDigits)
    Dim s As String
    s = FormatNumber(0.5, 1)
    If Mid(s, 2, 1) = Application.ThousandsSeparator Then ' WTF, thousands separator used as decimal separator
        FormatNumberFixed = Replace(FormatNumberFixed, Application.ThousandsSeparator, "%TMP%")
        FormatNumberFixed = Replace(FormatNumberFixed, Application.DecimalSeparator, Application.ThousandsSeparator)
        FormatNumberFixed = Replace(FormatNumberFixed, "%TMP%", Application.DecimalSeparator)
    End If
End Function
```

This can be used to format numbers "as expected", according to the settings in Excel.