# Excel decimal seperator changes when using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, decimal, settings

I set my Excel settings for decimal seperators to "."
This seems to work, since when I type `2.5` into a cell it recognizes it as a number and aligns it right.

Now I run the following code

```
dim string_var as string
string_var = .Cells(row, col).Value
.Cells(row, col).Value = string_var
```

I get `2,5` as output. 
Why and when did the `.` get replaced with the `,` and how can it be avoided? Is there a special decimal delimiter setting for VBA?

In the VBA Console I get:

```
debug.print(Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator))
.
debug.Print(Application.DecimalSeparator)
.
```

There is a related question without an answer: [Decimal Seperator different in VBA and Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918302/decimal-seperator-different-in-vba-and-excel) The comments refer to the regional settings.

Just in case you wonder why I need the value in a string variable. I have a large dataset with text and digits and lots of blanks. I need to clean the output and therefore would like to use the `string trim` function.

Comment: Do you have any cell formatting in place?

Comment: I've just tried that and it gives me `2.5`.. as expected. I suspect @SJR is correct, you may have some formatting somewhere that's causing the issue

Comment: Cell format ist `Standard`. I just tried to format the cells as number or text. I always get the same result. I still believe it has to do with some of my excel/vba settings

Comment: Did you check what your Windows System settings are as opposed to your excel settings? (like other question suggested?)

Comment: My Windows settings should be German and therefore using "," as a decimal seperator. In the excel settings I unchecked the checkbox so excel does not use the system settings and use the "." decimal instead. I did this via options -> advanced

Comment: have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532857/vba-display-decimals-with-point-and-not-coma