# VBA Userform function max and min

Tags: excel, vba, userform

**Can you tell me why when I introduce values on textbox27,28... it needs to be like 6.1 instead of 6,1? I wanted to insert values with "," and the result also appeared with ",". Thanks :)**

```
TextBox95.Text = WorksheetFunction.max(TextBox27.Text, TextBox28.Text, TextBox29.Text, TextBox30.Text, TextBox31.Text, TextBox32.Text, TextBox33.Text, TextBox34.Text) - WorksheetFunction.min(TextBox27.Text, TextBox28.Text, TextBox29.Text, TextBox30.Text, TextBox31.Text, TextBox32.Text, TextBox33.Text, TextBox34.Text)

TextBox96.Text = WorksheetFunction.max(TextBox19.Text, TextBox20.Text, TextBox21.Text, TextBox22.Text, TextBox23.Text, TextBox24.Text, TextBox25.Text, TextBox26.Text) - WorksheetFunction.min(TextBox19.Text, TextBox20.Text, TextBox21.Text, TextBox22.Text, TextBox23.Text, TextBox24.Text, TextBox25.Text, TextBox26.Text)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532857/vba-display-decimals-with-point-and-not-coma

Comment: What exactly should I change? I didn't understand

Comment: You need to understand what `Application.DecimalSeparator` is. You need to understand how windows and VBE understand the decimal separator. And then finally you have to make the decision whether you want to handle that in code or you want to change your system settings? If you are planning to distribute the file then I recommend handling it via VBA.

Answer (score -1):

The ',' is the thousands separator

2,000.2 = 2000.22

2,0 treated as text.

Hope to help you ;)

Comment: TextBox93.Text = WorksheetFunction.max(TextBox11.Text - TextBox15.Text, TextBox12.Text - TextBox16.Text, TextBox13.Text - TextBox17.Text, TextBox14.Text - TextBox18.Text, TextBox15.Text - TextBox11.Text, TextBox16.Text - TextBox12.Text, TextBox17.Text - TextBox13.Text, TextBox18.Text - TextBox14.Text) Here It works, I put values with "," and the result comes with ","