# Adding thousand-separators and apostrophe to a number won't show the separators unless i remove the apostrophe?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro to add separators and an apostrophe at the beginning of a number:

```
Sub Apostrofe()
Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
For Each cell In Selection
    cell.Value = "'" & cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Output for 123456789 is 123.456.789 but when it adds the apostrophe at the beginning, the format is lost. On the formula bar i see '123456789 but the separators won't appear unless i remove the apostrophe from the number.

I tried to concat the number in parts while manually adding the ' and . but the result is the same.
Adding the apostrophe in the Format of the code added it on the cell but it wouldn't appear on the formula bar.

If i manually write the apostrophe + number with separators it works but i receive hundreds of numbers which must be formatted this way.

How can i modify the macro to do what i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an apostrophe the value will be converted to text.

It seems that in your example you do not change the value itself (to the text equivalent containing the formated number), you just apply the format to the cell and then overwrite it with '.

I think you should try following code:

```
cell.NumberFormat = "@"    ' set cell format to text
cell.Value = Format(cell.Value, "#,##0")    ' Format() returns formated number as a string
```

Comment: Thanks! This adds the separators and lets me add the ' without losing format.
The only problem i'm trying to fix is that the separators is comma and changing your Format from "#,##0" to "#.##0" does not work as it considers the dot as decimal separator (both my regional and excel settings have dot as the thousand separator)

Comment: In the VBA editor, the decimal separator is the dot. So format string must stay as is or maybe you will want to use: '#,##0.##0'
However the problem is that the Format function will use Windows regional settings to produce result:
    Application.DecimalSeparator
    Application.ThousandsSeparator
Possibly this is your problem :) I don't know what exactly do you want to achieve, but for this particular case (if you really need to use string for number representation), then most probably you will have to use string replace function...

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532857/vba-display-decimals-with-point-and-not-coma